# Conditional Property in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

We've got an AWS CloudFormation template for creating some EC2 instances. Some of those however require a specific `PrivateIpAddress` and I'm struggling to figure out how to incorporate that to the template.

For now I've got a template parameter `PrivateIP` and a creating a Condition `RequestedPrivateIP`. So far so good. However I can't figure out how to incorporate it to the `AWS::EC2::Instance` resource specification. I tried this:

```
    "PrivateIpAddress": {
        "Fn::If": [ "RequestedPrivateIP",
            { "Ref": "PrivateIP" },
            ""                            <-- This doesn't work
        ]
    },
```

But that fails when `RequestedPrivateIP` is false with

```
CREATE_FAILED    AWS::EC2::Instance    NodeInstance    Invalid addresses: []
```

Any idea how to optionally assign a static Private IP and if not specified leave it to AWS to set a dynamic one?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

i would change the structure to:

```
"PrivateIpAddress": {
    "Fn::If": [ "RequestedPrivateIP",
        { "Ref": "PrivateIP" },
        {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue" }
    ]
}
```

the AWS::NoValue is there to give you the else option for your if statement.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like the `PrivateIpAddress` property does not support an empty string as it value, I would suggest creating two separate resources of your `AWS::EC2::Instance`. One of them will have your condition `RequestedPrivateIP` while the other one should have the same condition but negated, e.g. `DidNotRequestPrivateIP`.

```
"InstanceWithPrivateIp": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Condition": "RequestedPrivateIP",
    "Properties": {
        [...]
    }
},

"InstanceWithoutPrivateIp": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Condition": "DidNotRequestPrivateIP",
    "Properties": {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: That's indeed an option but severely breaks the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle that I'm not keen to do. Besides - there are often other properties that may or may not be set, for instance whether ELB listens on HTTPS based on whether a SSL certificate has been set. Trying to catch all these little variations by repeating all the declarations with a slight change would quickly lead to a massive unmaintainable template. But thanks for suggestion anyway.

Comment: I totally agree with you @MLu, repeating is never fun. However, from my experience with CloudFormation you're sometime forced to repeat yourself. The other solution I see is to create substacks instead that you include with the conditions I mentioned above and then in those substacks you do stuff that's specific for that condition.